# Changing an Object property value via mathematical expression in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the value of a property through a function method. I have it working but not exactly how i need it to work. Right now based of of user input it adds the number to value of speed. But not in a mathematical way. Instead it just adds it to the end of the value. so instead of doing 12 + 2 and getting 14. I get 122. How do i get it to add the values together?

### HTML

```
<form>      
    <input type="number" id="speed" min="-6" max="15" required>
    <input type="button" id="gear_submit" value="Submit" onclick="createBike();">
</form>
<p id="show_speed"></p>
```

### Javascript

```
function createBike(){
    function bike(model, speed){
        this.model = model;
        this.speed = speed;

    // this will change speed based on user input
        this.changeSpeed = function (changeSpeed) {
            var new_speed = document.getElementById("speed").value;
            if (new_speed > 0 ){
                bikeArray[0].speed = speed + new_speed;
            }
            else if (new_speed < 0 ){
                bikeArray[0].speed - speed - new_speed;
            }
        }
    }

    var bike1 = new bike("Ghost Ryder", "12");
    bikeArray[0] = bike1;

    bike1.changeSpeed();

    document.getElementById("show_speed").innerHTML = bikeArray[0].model + " " + bikeArray[0].speed;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's treating your numbers as strings, and concatenating the strings instead of adding the numbers. To fix this you need to first remove the quotes around the number in your constructor so that it's a number and not a string, and secondly you need to use `parseInt` on the value that comes from your `speed` input element.

**Working Example:**

```js
var bikeArray = [];

function createBike() {
  function bike(model, speed) {
    this.model = model;
    this.speed = speed;

    // this will change speed based on user input
    this.changeSpeed = function(changeSpeed) {
      /* The value on the following line gets parsed using parseInt */
      var new_speed = parseInt(document.getElementById("speed").value, 10);
      bikeArray[0].speed = speed + new_speed;
    }
  }

  /* The object gets initialized using an integer value here instead of a string */
  var bike1 = new bike("Ghost Ryder", 12);
  bikeArray[0] = bike1;

  bike1.changeSpeed();

  document.getElementById("show_speed").innerHTML = bikeArray[0].model + " " + bikeArray[0].speed;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="speed" min="-6" max="15" required>
  <input type="button" id="gear_submit" value="Submit" onclick="createBike();">
</form>
<p id="show_speed"></p>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/a453bngn/2/

Comment: two things. the parseint() for new_speed, is the ",10" setting it to base 10?...then also while you demo does work i noticed for the if else it would need to be addition as well because if you subtract a neg number it does addition. just incase someone else looks at this

Comment: @kronis72 That is correct, the `10` is forcing `parseInt` to parse in base 10.

Comment: i just noticed the subtracting issue myself

Comment: @kronis72 It looks like your `if else` statement was redundant, so I removed it and it looks like subtraction is working fine now as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the variable as a number, not a string.  `parseInt()` does this.

```
bikeArray[0].speed = parseInt(speed, 10) + parseInt(new_speed, 10);
```

Comment: If OP uses this answer, then his speed variable will start out as a string and then later become an integer. It's not great to change types like that.

Comment: please add the base to `parseInt`.